# Can't move Rigidbody2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, unityscript

I can't seem to get my guy to move left and right. The code I'm doing for it, I think is correct. He has a `Rigidbody2D` component attached to him and the script attached as well.

I think it may be something to do with `InputManager` settings, but that all looks fine.

Edge collider is registered as "Ground" tag. I set the values of those public variables in the inspector panel each to 10.

```
function OnCollisionEnter2D(coll: Collision2D){
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
        canJump = true;
    }
}

function OnCollisionExit2D(coll: Collision2D){
    if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Ground"){
        canJump = false;
    }
}

function Update(){
    Debug.Log("this: "+canJump);
}

function FixedUpdate () {
    var movementInput : float = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");

    if (canJump){
        //move left or right whilst jumping
        characterBod.AddForce(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime * hzSpeed * movementInput, 0), ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }else{
    //move left or right whilst on ground
        canJump = false;
        characterBod.AddForce(new Vector2(Time.deltaTime * hzJumpSpeed * movementInput, 0), ForceMode2D.Force);
    }
    if (Input.GetButton("Jump") && canJump){
        characterBod.velocity = Vector2(0, jumpVelocity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using ForceMode2D.Impulse? What happen if you change it to Force?